# How to load a MSSQL DB using MySQL in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, sql-server

I have a MSSQL DB, and would like to convert it to a MySQL DB so I could browse it from Ubuntu. What packages/tools do I need to install and what are the steps for achieving this? Thanks

Comment: have you tried these suggestions? http://stackoverflow.com/q/129/1067827

Comment: you can also "browse" an SQL Server database from Ubuntu without exporting/importing into MySQL. There might be better options, but http://www.squirrelsql.org/ + SQL Server JDBC driver will let you connect to the db, which might be a more practical option.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to export the MSSQL data in a common format, such as CSV, and them import it into mysql.

You use **bcp** to export data from MSSQL into custom-format files; on the mysql side, use LOAD DATA or the equivalent.

The schema is another matter; since the SQL dialects are wildly different, this will require manual manipulation of the MSSQL schema output.